# Check content of web page in cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I'm starting to explore BDD and Cucumber.
So I want to check if my page displays the content of 2 articles I have.
This is the step I'm using the check if the content is there:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |desc|
 page.should have_content desc

 expected = Article.find_by_description(desc)
 page.should have_content(expected.navision_code)
 page.should have_content(expected.category.name)
end
```

Normally this should do the trick I guess but when I run the test I got this error message:

```
expected there to be content "---\n- tenetur\n" in "Alfa Paints Order System\n\n\n\nAlfa Paints\n\n\n\nSeth abernathy, admin\n\n\nVerander paswoord\n\nLogout\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nAlfa Paints\nordering system\n\n\n\n\n\nOverzicht van alle artikelen\n\n\n\nBack\n\n\n\n\n\n\nProduct ID\nBeschrijving\nCategorie\n3001\nPaint\n---\n- tenetur\n\n3002\nBrush\n---\n- tenetur\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
./features/step_definitions/admin_articles_steps.rb:41:in `/^I should see "([^"]*)"$/'
features/admin_articles.feature:10:in `Then I should see "Paint"'
```

As you can see I expect paint and the error message shows the content has paint inside.
But somehow cucumber isn't recognizing it.

I'm new to cucumber and I'm probably missing something but maybe somebody could help me on my way.

Comment: It looks like Capybara doesn't play well with newlines. You might try stripping them out with something like this: http://praktikanten.brueckenschlaeger.org/2011/11/15/working-in-cucumber-with-new-lines-and-have_content

Comment: I don't think you need to determine the "entire" article is there for a "successful" test, maybe check for random lines in the article?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for three things at once, so it is difficult to tell which of the expectations is failing. As a first step, try commenting out everything but the first expectation just to make sure its failing where you think.

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |desc|
 page.should have_content desc

// expected = Article.find_by_description(desc)
// page.should have_content(expected.navision_code)
// page.should have_content(expected.category.name)
end
```

If you still have the same problem, add debugger so that you can experiment and see what is going on from inside your test environment. This is a skill worth developing if you plan to do much cucumber testing.

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |desc|
 debugger
 page.should have_content desc
end
```

From debug console, see what the desc variable and page look like:

```
p desc
p page.content
```